# Diffrence between sessionFactory Vs HttpSession ? in Spring+Hibernate Application?

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

What is difference between them and i want to know that which one of these are use for Session Maintenance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Session Factory** is the Abstraction that is used to create
sessions which are used to get a physical connection(database session) with a database. The Session object is lightweight and designed to be instantiated each time an interaction is needed with the database. Persistent objects are saved and retrieved through a Session object.

**HttpSession** object represents a user session. A user session contains information about the user across multiple HTTP requests.

When a user enters your site for the first time, the user is given a unique ID to identify his session. This ID is typically stored in a cookie or in a request parameter.

Answer (score 1):

The Hibernate SessionFactory object allows you to create a session for your database, from which you can perform your queries.

The HttpSession on the otherhand is the user session for your web application.  You can use this to store information about the user, which you may need to reuse.